Uniform extension of Holder functions
Let $\{\Omega_t\}_{t\in [0,1]} \subseteq \Omega'$ where $\Omega_t$ is a $C^{k,\alpha}$ uniformly convex domain and $\Omega'$ is open and bounded. Suppose $u_t \in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega_t)$, then one may extend $u_t$ to $\tilde u_t \in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega')$ such that
$$
\| \tilde{u}_t \|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega'})} \leq C_t \| u_t \|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega_t)}
$$
for some $C_t$ depending on $\Omega_t$ and $\Omega'$.
Can we find a uniform constant $C$ independent of $t$ such that
$$
\| \tilde{u}_t \|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega')} \leq C \| u_t \|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega_t)}?
$$
That is, can we control $C_t$ uniformly over $t\in [0,1]$?

The uniform extension is possible when the domains are also controlled uniformly in terms of their curvature. For each $t$, let $h_t\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega')$ be a uniformly convex function such that
$$
{\rm int}(\Omega_t)  = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: h_t(x)<0\}.
$$
By inspecting the proof of the extension theorem in Trudinger's Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order, we know that $C_t$ can be controlled uniformly once we have controlled $C^{k,\alpha}$ diffeomorphisms uniformly. A candidate diffeomorphism is
$$
\Psi_t : x:=(x_1,\cdots,x_d)\mapsto (x_1,\cdots,x_{d-1},-h_t(x)).
$$
Hence, if $\sup_t\|h_t\|_{C^{k,\alpha}}<\infty$, then one mayobtain that $\sup_t C_t<\infty$.
